How to establish this generalization rule in sequent calculus for First Order Logic?
I stumbled across this rule:
$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash q\rightarrow p(a) }{\Gamma \vdash (q \rightarrow \forall x. p(x))}$$
where $a$ also needs to be a fresh constant, so with that in mind you could re-write the rule as the following:
$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash q\rightarrow p(a)\hspace{1cm} a\text{ is fresh}}{\Gamma \vdash (q \rightarrow \forall x. p(x))}$$.
The calculus I'm working with is a standard sequent calculus, without the weakening rules, and for the quantifier, I also have the following rule, which is very similar:
$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash  p(a)\hspace{1cm} a\text{ is fresh}}{\Gamma \vdash  \forall x. p(x)}\text{$\forall$R}$$.
I tried several approaches to derive the first (or second) rule without any success, is it possible to do that?

To prove that $\forall x: [P(x) \implies Q(x)]$, you need only prove $P(a)\implies Q(a)$ for "fresh $a$."

... Where the predicate $P$ here could be seen as the possibly empty domain of  discussion or quantification.

The idea is that (using a top-down approach) you first have to decompose the formula $q \to p(a)$ using the rules $\to_L$ and cut, then you apply $\forall_R$ to $p(a)$, and finally, you recompose the formula $q \to \forall x. p(x)$ using $\to_R$.
Note that this is possible because you are assuming that $a$ is fresh, which means that it does not occur free in $\Gamma$ and $q$, otherwise the rule $\forall_R$ could not be applied.
$$
\dfrac
{
  \lower{1.5ex}{\Gamma \vdash q \to p(a)}
  \qquad
  \dfrac{
    \dfrac{}{q \vdash q}\text{ax} 
    \qquad 
    \dfrac{}{p(a) \vdash p(a)}\text{ax}
  }
  {q, \, q\to p(a)\vdash p(a)}
  \to_L
}
{
  \dfrac
  {
    \dfrac{\Gamma, q \vdash  p(a)}{\Gamma, q \vdash  \forall x.p(x)}\forall_R
    }
  {\Gamma \vdash q \to \forall x.p(x)}
  \to_R
}
\text{cut}
$$

This worked perfectly, I tried to apply the cut rule in different parts of the derivation without success, thanks a lot :)

@gggg - You're welcome!
